# Error 403 OpenApi with SpringBoot security filter chain

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I was trying to add OpenApi documentation to my spring-boot app, but when i try to connect to /v3/api-docs and /swagger-ui error 403 occurs.

I'm using springBoot 3.0.1 and springdoc-openapi-ui dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.15</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding permitAll for requests matchings in security filter chain.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(customAuthenticationManager, userService);
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/authenticate");
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                        "/proxy/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter)
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), AuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

as well as adding WebSecurityCustomizer bean with web.ignore()

```
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**","/proxy/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v3/api-docs/**");
    }
```

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: @times29 I'm using 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dependency

First, you need to use a different dependency for Spring Boot 3:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Find the most recent version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui).

## Security Config

To me, your security config looks fine. I also excluded the `"/webjars/swagger-ui/**"` but I'm not sure, if it is really necessary. The following config works for me:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String[] SWAGGER_PATHS = {"/swagger-ui.html", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/swagger-ui/**"};

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(SWAGGER_PATHS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .build();
    }
}
```